# Always resume back at my app's main form/activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-intent

My Android app has a button that executes this code in order to open the app market pointing to a certain app.

It works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.app_url)));
startActivity(intent);
```

But whenever the user exits my app at that point, by hitting HOME, the next time he reopens it (resuming it, even days later), the app is STILL pointing at the app store.

How do I make any "reopening" always return back to my app's make form/activity?
(Same as if he had hit BACK, instead of HOME, when he exited my app yesterday.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From google + android developers post.

> If your application launches the activities of other applications (such as to view a picture or pick an attachment), there is an important intent flag to know:
>
> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
>
> Use this when starting an activity that you don't want the user to return to if they relaunch your application from the app launcher or a shortcut on the home screen. For example, it would be confusing to tap on the Gmail icon and find yourself selecting a picture because that is the last thing you had been doing as part of the Gmail task.

Answer (score 1):

Before startActivity(), try this:

`intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

If you would like the activity that this is called from to clean up & forget its state as well, call finish() after startActivity() too.